# Change words but retain format and character casing

Tags: replace

What is the most convenient way to do search and replace for same words in multiple formats. I often find myself doing tons of regular expressions as follows.

```
:%s/scubaDiver/deviceDriver/g
:%s/ScubaDiver/DeviceDriver/g
:%s/scuba_diver/device_driver/g
:%s/Scuba_diver/Device_driver/g
:%s/scuba-diver/device-driver/g
:%s/Scuba-diver/Device-driver/g
:%s/SCUBA-DIVER/DEVICE-DRIVER/g
```

Answer (score 1):

The [vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plug-in has a [`:Subvert`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish#substitution) command that does something very close to what you want.

This command covers 5 of the 7 cases you mentioned:

```
%Subvert/scuba{_,-,}Diver/device{_,-,}Driver
```

It doesn't seem to cover the cases with a delimiter and mixed case, in specific `Scuba_diver` and `Scuba-diver`, presumably because it will try to define the most common capitalizations you'd encounter in coding conventions (camel case, snake case, etc.) Maybe there's a way to get it to cover all these exact cases, but it wasn't immediately apparent to me how to do so (digging further might uncover it.)